Bluetooth microphone headset with noise canceling
This is an old problem, it's hard to make the microphone work when using your Bluetooth headset.
I've heard of people using pipewire rather than pulseaudio claiming resolution of all problems and others saying it doesn't change anything.
Currently, on Ubuntu 20.04 I can use the microphone with low quality and no noise canceling.
If I used pipewire, is there a way to use the microphone with the ANC?
Since on my phone it works properly, why is not possible to do that with my laptop?
Thanks for your help.
